# How to run different sub jobs based on git change on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

My project is large, encompassing many sub projects on git.

I have a Jenkins job running when there is a merge request in the project.

However, whenever there is a change, it builds the whole project, which is a waste of time. I separated many sub jobs for each sub project. The question is, how could I only run the specific sub job based on the change addressed in that sub project from each merge request instead of running the whole build every time?

Thanks guys!